# Outlook template pull up Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a list of Data that contains various entry details (Made by, Date, Amount, etc.) stored on a excel worksheet. I am trying to auto support to people who made the entries in the first place.

My goals for the macro I'm writing are:

1. Create a mail object
2. Set mail object to outlook template file
3. setting and then filling in the template with data about the original entry writer (thats who I will be sending it to), the comment they left about the entry, and pulling some other details for the template.
4. Save to drafts for later review/send

This what I have to far:

```
Sub SendMail()
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
         Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem 
         Dim  blRunning As Boolean

         blRunning = True 
         on Error Resume Next 
         Set olApp = GetObject (,"Outlook.Application") 
         If olApp Is Nothing Then 
             Set olApp = New Outlook.Application 
             blRunning = False 
        End If  
        On Error GoTo 0 

        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
        With olMail 
            .Subject = "Automatic Entry Support" 
            .Recipients.Add "J.Doe@gmail.com"  
            .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\J.Doe\Documents\Project\Template draft.xlsx"  
            .Body = "Support message" 
            .Display ("Spell check, data attached?, SEND")
        End With
        If Not blRunning Then olApp.Quit

        Set olApp = Nothing
        Set olMail = Nothing
    End Sub
```

(There are lines in the code that I placed with "fake" lines to not show anything important).

Also, this is my first post on this site so please comment if I am not asking the question in the right format.

**UPDATE**: I am also receiving an error when trying to run the code: "Run-time error '-2147024894 (8007002): Automation error"

Comment: Asking for a tutorial makes the Q off topic.  I removed that to save you from down votes and close votes.

Comment: Is `.Body = "..." .Display (...)` on the same line in your real code, or is that just an issue posting here.  They need to be on separate lines

Comment: Thank you Chris. It won't happen again!

Comment: For typed it out wrong. They are on separate lines in my macro. I'll edit it on the post. Sorry again.

Comment: There are several other typos too. `Sub Send Mail()` --> `Sub SendMail()` , `Dim blRunning As Boolen` --> `Dim blRunning As Boolean` , `Set olMaill = Nothing` --> `Set olMail = Nothing`Again, are these real code issues or posting issues?

Comment: What are trying to do with `.Display ("Spell check, data attached?, SEND")` ? [see help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-display-method-outlook)

Comment: Addressing your first question about the spelling issues, I'm afraid its just the post and not the real code again (typing to fast). Addressing your second question I am trying to display a message for the user of the template/outlook email to check the email before sending and to remember to send (which is ironic that it says spell check on it).

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? What line of code exactly throws an exception?

Comment: The error comes up when debugging the line:  .Body = "Support Message"

Comment: Code runs file for me (once typos are fixed).  BTW the string parameter you pass to `Display` does nothing, you should remove it

Comment: Ok it is removed. I still receive the same run-time error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .Body = "Support message"
```

You may try to set the `BodyFormat` before setting the message body.

Most probably you have faced with a security issue in Outlook. "Security" in this context refers to the so-called "object model guard" that triggers security prompts and blocks access to certain features in an effort to prevent malicious programs from harvesting email addresses from Outlook data and using Outlook to propagate viruses and spam.

Possible workarounds are:

1. [Outlook Security Manager](http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) which allows to disable and enable security in Outlook dynamically.
2. A low-level code which doesn't trigger security issues (Extended MAPI).
3. Develop a COM add-in. In order to avoid Outlook object model security prompts, the add-in must derive all Outlook objects from this Outlook.Application object. In VSTO add-ins, that would be the `Globals.ThisAddin.Application` object.
4. Deploying a GPO policy.

Read more about possible options in the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52) article.

Comment: okay I will try out one of those suggestions. Thank you. That solves the body problem. Is there a way to write a macro that will pull the original entry creator out of a pivot table or table field into the recipient section? I'm trying to automate the whole process of email multiple users from this data table. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd recommend marking the right answer and asking separate questions in new threads.